# How to check multiple columns?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem because when i have in variable $name = "firstname lastname", i got nothing, but if i enter only firstname or only lastname i get result. I want to check both columns so when user enter firstname lastname that gets user with firstname lastname. Any suggestion?
I have this query:

```
$q->orWhere('first_name','like','%' .$name . '%')->orWhere('last_name','like','%' . $name . '%');
```

I tried this with union:

```
$q->orWhere('first_name','like','%' .$name . '%')->union('last_name','like','%' . $name . '%');
```

but i get this error:

> Call to a member function getBindings() on string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name can be just one word or three words, so you need to `explode()` string first and then add conditionals:

```
$user = User::query();

$nameArray = explode(' ', trim($name));

foreach ($nameArray as $nameSegment) {
    $user->orWhere('first_name', 'like', '%'.$nameSegment.'%');
         ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%'.$nameSegment.'%');
}

$user->get();
```